# Angular ReactiveForms - How to set validators to whole FormGroup

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I currently have a very large form.

I have the following validators for each field, for example:

```
this.surname = new FormControl('', [
      Validators.pattern(/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+[_.\- /\\]{0,1})*([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/i),
      Validators.minLength(3),
      Validators.maxLength(30),
      Validators.required
    ]);
```

and the same for each field. Is it possible not to repeat the code and apply the same rules for everyone? I just tried:

```
formGroupName.setValidators([Validators.required]);
```

but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

1.-Use a auxiliar variable

```
const validators=[
      Validators.pattern(/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+[_.\- /\\]{0,1})*([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/i),
      Validators.minLength(3),
      Validators.maxLength(30),
      Validators.required
    ]
this.surname = new FormControl('',validators)
```

2.-Use setValidator iterating over the controls

```
Object.keys(this.form).forEach(key=>{
     this.form.get(key).setValidators(Validators.required)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

FormGroup accepts validator as a second paramater. you can pass array of A synchronous validator function like this:

**Try this:**

```
 this.form.group({
      lastName: ['', ],
      firstName: ['', ]
    },{
      validator: [Validators.required]
    });
```